# Filter on multiple criteria defined in one cell

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, filter

I want to apply an autofilter with multiple criteria for 1 field, i.e. the value in the 'InputColumnNo' should have value A or B. The problem is that my definition of these filter criteria should be entered in one cell in Excel. 
I tried to use an array for that and enter something like "(A,B)" in Cell F7 and then using below code, but that doesn't work. Is there anyone who can help me?

```
Value = Range("F7")
wsinput.Rows(1).AutoFilter field:=InputColumnNo, Criteria1:=Array(Value),
VisibleDropDown:=False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using or filter where I have "A,B" in `Range("I2")`

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

Dim value As String
value = Range("I2")
Dim valuesArr() As String

valuesArr = Split(value, ",")

    ActiveSheet.Range("$F$1:$G$5").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=valuesArr(0), _
        Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:=valuesArr(1)
End Sub
```

**And assigning from array**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

Dim value As String
value = Range("I2")
Dim valuesArr() As String

valuesArr = Split(value, ",")

    ActiveSheet.Range("$F$1:$G$5").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=valuesArr, Operator:=xlFilterValues

End Sub
```